# Proper multithreaded usage of .Net web reference client

Tags: .net, multithreading, soap, task-parallel-library, webservice-client

I have to consume a .net 2.0 era .asmx web service that I didn't build and can't control.  However the service is highly available and can handle this.

What I need help with is the client, and using the visual studio generated client proxy correctly from a concurency stand point.  Currently I am using a Web Reference, but can switch to a Service Reference if needed.  I know nothing about WCF though.

The more I read, the more I confuse myself.

My specific questions:

Given a visual studio generated soap client proxy that produces methods along the lines of:

```
Foo();
FooAsync();
FooCompleted;

Bar();
BarAsync();
BarCompleted;
```

1. should/can i call Foo() from more than one thread, like in a Parallel.ForEach?
2. should/can i call FooAsync() inside the parallel foreach?  This seems redundant, since I'm already on another thread? Is it safe to do this?
3. Should/can i call FooAsync() on one thread, while calling BarAsync() on another thread?
4. These generated soap service classes seem to implement the EAP pattern. I'm brand new to pfx/tpl stuff, but I have been looking at tasks as a way to better manage some of this?  I have seen examples of how to wrap EAP with Task using TaskCompletionSource.  Is that the better approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can call `Foo()` on as many threads as you want (you will have to make the decision regarding whether you *should*, yourself). They run (like you suggest) as if they were running in parallel.
2. I have provided an example of something like what you want using the Task Parallel Library [(TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) below. It is redundant to spawn a thread for `FooAsync()` if you have already spawned one for `Foo()` but this depends on what precisely you are doing or want to do. Typically you would call `Foo()` from the UI thread, which in turn would launch the `FooAsync()` on a separate thread.

   ```
   private void Foo()
   {
       // Get TaskScheduler to facilitate manipulation of GUI on UI Thread.
       TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

       // Cancellation support.
       CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
       CancellationToken token = cancelSource.Token;

       // Spin-off onto background thread.
       Task<bool> asyncFooTask = null;
       asyncFooTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => asyncFoo(uiScheduler, token, _dynamic), token);

       // Continuation/call-back/error-handling.
       asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
       {
           // Check task status.
           switch (task.Status)
           {
               // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
               case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                   if (asyncTask.Result)
                       // Success. Do stuff.
                   else
                       // Failed. Do stuff.
                   break;
               case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                   if (task.Exception != null)
                       // Cancelled with exception.
                   else
                       // User cancelled.
                   break;
               case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                   if (task.Exception != null)
                       // AggregateException thrown by antecident.
                   else
                       // Task failed...
                   break;
           }
           return;
       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
   }
   ```

See this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) for a great introduction to TPL and its use. Also, for more information on generic threading (and some different guises), see [J. Albahari's Threading Page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

3 This is totally subjective and depends on what you want to do. Like answer 1 suggests, you can call each of these methods on as many threads as you want.

4 For a great example of the EAP pattern [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454.aspx). As you will see, it is essentially what I have provided above. For the above methods, I assume you want to run 'FooCompleted()`and 'BarCompleted()` after `FooAsync()` and `BarAsync()` have completed. In this case, I would say the EPL pattern is precisely what you want.

I hope this helps.